# How Set Action Bar Menu Position To Right

Tags: java, android

I am making a app where I have hide the action bar and added imageview to open menu.

But I am seeing menu on left top corner like this 
[image]

```
   getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

I Have used this method to call

```
public void openactionmenu() {
        NewMainActivity.this.openOptionsMenu();
    }
```

How can I get the menu on the right side

Comment: Can you please send a pic of your code?

Comment: Please DO NOT send `pic of code` just show your code, what have you try, in here as forum support it,

Comment: view this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922454/how-to-open-menu-in-activity-from-fragment (this is my previous question)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !!

I did it by adding popup menu

follow this - https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-popup-menu-with-examples